SwiftUI - nested ForEach causes compiler confusion
I'm drawing connected shapes, where a shape can connect to one or more downstream shapes.
The data model is straightforward:
@Observable class GadgetModel: Encodable, Identifiable {
    var gadgets  = [GadgetNode]() {
            }
        }
    }

Each gadget (shape) is identified by a unique id, and an enum with associated data that defines stuff that isn't relevant to this little problem.
I originally made this a class, and chained gadget references together. Which worked fine. However, in the interest of converting this to a struct (easier to json), I'm replacing the single input and output with arrays of the ids of other gadgets in the data model:
@Observable class GadgetNode : Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
public var gadgetType: GadgetType = .unassigned
public var id: Int = 0             // GadgetNodes and GadgetViews share the same id

var input1: GadgetNode?
var output1: GadgetNode?
var inputs:  [Int] = []   // use the ID of the nodes rather than a reference.
var outputs: [Int] = []

To draw them, I iterate over the data model elements with a ForEach, where a function call returns a view for each of the data model elements (gadgets). Next, I try to draw a line that connects the outputs of each node to the inputs of each dependent node. Such a simple concept (and easy when there were only a fixed number of connections). So impossible as soon as I try to iterate over the output connections!
Here's the working code for the version that just has one output node from each gadget:
                ZStack {
                    ForEach(gadgetModel.gadgets) { gadget in
                        getGadgetView(gadget: gadget)
                        let myPosition = gadget.position
                        if let outputPosition  = gadget.output1?.position {
                                DataFlowLine(
                                    from: myPosition,
                                    to: outputPosition)
                            .animation(.easeInOut, value: outputPosition)
                        }
                     }
 

Here's the drawing code for a version where each gadget has an array of the ids of downstream, or output gadgets:
 struct GadgetDocumentView: View {
    @Environment(GadgetModel.self) private var gadgetModel

.
.
.                  ForEach(gadgetModel.gadgets, id: \.self) { gadget in
                        getGadgetView(gadget: gadget)
                            let myPosition = gadget.position
                            ForEach(gadget.outputs) { output in
                                let outputPosition  = gadgetModel.gadgets[output].position {
                                    DataFlowLine(
                                        from: myPosition,
                                        to: outputPosition)
                                }
                        }
                    }    // ForEach gadget

But, it won't compile, because the delightfully "helpful" message "Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'some View' conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent' " appears - presumably because the different views need to be smooshed together with a @ViewBuilder (which is how getGadgetView can return any of a number of different views).
So, I tried separating the drawing of the gadgets from the drawing of the connecting lines:
           ZStack {
                // Draw the gadgets
                ForEach(gadgetModel.gadgets, id: \.self) { gadget in
                    getGadgetView(gadget: gadget)
                }
                // For each gadget, draw lines to each downstream gadget
                ForEach(gadgetModel.gadgets, id: \.self) { gadget in
                     let myPosition = gadget.position
                    Group {
                        ForEach(gadget.outputs) { output in
                            let outputPosition  = gadgetModel.gadgets[output].position {
                                DataFlowLine(
                                    from: myPosition,
                                    to: outputPosition)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }    // ForEach gadget
            ```

Now I get different errors - on this occasion, the compiler complains that it wants a binding ... even though I only want values from the data model, and never modify them here. Or I get an error message explaining that the code is too complex to evaluate, and needs to be broken down into pieces.
I've got to say that I'm confused by SwifUI's intransigence.
Do I need to put these together using a @ViewBuilder function? I tried embedding the lines into a Group, but that didn't help.
Ideas?
Unfortunately, doing even the simplest thing in SwiftUI can be like opening up a booby-trapped door into undocumented weirdness.

Is let outputPosition = ... supposed to be if let outputPosition = ...?

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: Minimal code.
Currently you show some bits of views without a body and a ForEach
without any context. We cannot replicate your errors because you do not show
enough of your code. Note, your gadgets in GadgetModel seems to be a computed property,
is that correct?  Also, gadget.outputs is an array [Int], so you probably should have
ForEach(gadget.outputs, id: \.self)

Thanks for your comments. Yes, this is simplified code.

Sorry about the typo - if let outputPosition is used where output is optional - if there is a pointer to an output node, a line is drawn.   No, gadgets is not a computed property - it's simply an array of GadgetNode. So the singleton instance of the data model, gadgetModel, contains an array called gadgets, where each element of the array is an GadgetNode.  I thought that the problem was likely so simple for someone ELSE to spot that it didn't warrant showing complete source code (although it's pretty close).

Thanks again - I appreciate your interest.

You are a hero - thanks! I thought that I had tried ForEach(gadget.output, id: .self) without success. BUT, I made that simple change, and tada - it works!
